# How to get even or odd numbers

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I don't know why this program doesn't works. I get a random number and the computer select what type it is even or odd ?

```
Dim a As New Random()

    Dim b As Integer
    Dim ca As Integer
    b = a.Next(0, 10)
    Debug.Print(b)

    ca = b / 2

    If ca = 0 Then
        Debug.Print("Even")
    Else
        Debug.Print("Odd")
    End If
```

Comment: look at `Mod`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are messing up your operators.

You use division `/`, but you want to use the modulo operator `Mod`.

Please note: in C# it is `%`. In VB.Net it is `Mod`

Reference: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
Dim a As New Random()
Dim b As Integer
Dim ca As Integer
b = a.Next(0, 10)
Debug.Print(b)

ca = b Mod 2

If ca = 0 Then
    Debug.Print("Even")
Else
    Debug.Print("Odd")
End If
```

Why your code does not work as expected:
The culprit is indeed your if-statement. You are checking if the result of `b / 2` is 0. But this can only be true if `b` itself is 0. Every number greater then 0 devided by half is greater then zero.

Your code looks like you want to check for the rest of a division, hence the solution with the modulo operator.

Comment: I can't use modulo i need to do it this way. i think that the problem might be at if.

Comment: If you are not allowed to use the modulo operator check out @dbasnett solution below. It works without it.

Comment: I used the formula of the modulo and it works ca = b - (2 * (b \ 2))

Comment: This was one of the alternatives provided in the msdn documentation, yes?

Answer (score 7):

You could also just check the low order bit, if it is on the number is odd, if it is off the number is even.  Using a function:

```
    Dim a As New Random()
    Dim b As Integer
    b = a.Next(0, 10)
    Debug.WriteLine(b)
    If isEven(b) Then
        Debug.WriteLine("even")
    Else
        Debug.WriteLine("odd")
    End If

Private Function isEven(numToCheck As Integer) As Boolean
    Return (numToCheck And 1) = 0
End Function
```

edit: might be faster than mod but haven't checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private sub command1_click()
   Dim a as integer
   a = text1.text
   If a mod 2=0 then
      Print a & " is even"
   Else
      Print a & "is odd"
   Endif
End sub
```