# Using visual basic, what do I need to add to my for next loop to make my application display only even numbers?

Tags: vb.net, loops, for-loop, numbers

My question is not the same as the one it is flagged as similar to. I need my application to display the actual numbers that are even in a range of numbers entered by the user. The other question prints "Even" or "Odd" based on a number.

I am working on a homework assignment where I have to make my application take numbers that are input by the user in text boxes and display the even numbers between them in a list box using a For...Next statement. 
(So if the user enters 2 in the From box and 10 in the To box it, the application needs to output 2, 4, 6, 8, and 10 without commas in the list box.)

This is my current interface (Showing how the application runs with the current code):

[Numbers App Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5kPR.jpg)

This is my current code:

```
 Dim intFrom As Integer
        Dim intTo As Integer

        Integer.TryParse(txtFrom.Text, intFrom)
        Integer.TryParse(txtTo.Text, intTo)
        lstNumbers.Items.Clear()

        For intList As Integer = intFrom To intTo
            If intFrom >= intTo Then
                Exit For
            End If
            lstNumbers.Items.Add(intList)
        Next intList
    End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get even or odd numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24220929/how-to-get-even-or-odd-numbers)

Comment: @BorisSerafimov that question isn't quite the same as mine. The question you showed me is having an application print "Odd" or "Even" in a box based on a number. I need my application to display all even numbers in a range of numbers entered by the user.

Comment: `lstNumbers.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(intFrom, intTo- intFrom).Where(Function(n) n Mod 2 = 0).ToArray())`

Comment: @djv this brings up Error BC30456 'AddRange' is not a member of 'ListBox'. when I attempt to run the program.

Comment: Hint,  check for even (intList and 1) = 0.

Comment: @M.Ridgeway looks like you got an answer below. my apologies, yes it doesn't work on a listbox. This is a [frowned-upon] alternative `Enumerable.Range(intFrom, intTo- intFrom).Where(Function(n) n Mod 2 = 0).Select(Function(n) lstNumbers.Items.Add(n))` but i still like to do it in one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `For` cycle with this:

```
For intList As Integer = intFrom To intTo
        Dim result As Integer = intList Mod 2
        If result = 0 Then
            lstNumbers.Items.Add(intList)
        End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been looking at this problem since yesterday and nothing in my textbook helped.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives

```
    lstNumbers.Items.Clear()
    'alternative 1
    Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of String)
    ie = From i In Enumerable.Range(intFrom, intTo - intFrom + 1)
         Where (i And 1) = 0 Select CType(i, String)

    lstNumbers.Items.AddRange(ie.ToArray)

    lstNumbers.Items.Clear()
    'alternative 2
    For intList As Integer = intFrom To intTo
        If (intList And 1) = 0 Then
            lstNumbers.Items.Add(intList)
        End If
    Next
```